# The usage of "As you mentioned earlier" etc

Tags: usage, conjunctions, as, discourse-markers

How to use **as + subject + in/earlier/before/above** in the sentences while writing or speaking. I have often seen people using some expressing starting with "As", for examples:

- As you said/mentioned that . . .
- As you said earlier/before/above that . .
- As you mentioned in . . . .
- As it's previously mentioned . . .

Is  the use of "as" the same as "like" here?

Answer (score 2):

In that type of construction, use "As".  You will often hear "like" used in that and similar constructions, but it is *very* informal.

Answer (score 0):

This use of **As** is just like **Like**, in those constructions. Using 'Like' is informal or colloquial than 'As'.

The constructions you quoted:

- As you said/mentioned that . . .
- As you said earlier/before/above that . .
- As you mentioned in . . . .
- As it's previously mentioned . . .

We can also use 'As' to mean **since or because** in above constructions but I'd advice you to use 'As' to mean 'since or 'because' only in the construction with **that**, except for this, simply remove 'that' from the construction and use 'as' to mean 'Like'.